# Payment Merchants with easy IPN

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am looking to integrate to my website many payment merchants.
Now I have integrated PayPal and CCBill because they have easy to use IPN.

I want to send to the merchant data like: amount,1custom variable and the merchant should send to my IPN url the amount and the custom variable.

It would be nice if you can give me some names and links to their IPN documentation

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ! You're awesome.Too bad I cant rate your very usefull answer.Seriously,I know what google does,but I posted here because google cant tell me all the merchants that use IPN.It returns me thousands of pages with documentation about PayPal.If you want to feel yourself smart,provide a smart answer,not a rat face answer.

Comment: Your google-searching problem isn't Google's - merchants just call the IPN-style functionality different things. You will have to identify which gateways offer this kind of feature. I know for a fact that RBS WorldPay and SagePay both offer an IPN-like feature.

Comment: Thanks for answering nicely,unlike other people that think they are cool and ultra smart

Comment: Yes, WorldPay has IPN, but it is generally a PITA and their support is terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every other payment gateway has some sort of IPN mechanism. It should not be the key factor when you choose a payment processor. The key factor is the percentage of your target audience that the gateway can process. For example, if half of your audience prefers paying with their bank account, you should find a gateway that can do that. And do that well.

Comment: I know only about PayPal,MoneyBookers,CCBill,WorldPay,Authorize.net ... you know any others that support credit card payments instantly ?

Comment: HSBC (XML API), SagePay Direct